# Pytorch dataloader, returned shape of targets

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm running a Pytorch model training, where I defined the **getitem** method of the dataset to return:

```
def __getitem__(self, ind):
    [...]
    return processed_images, target
```

processed_images is a sequence of 5 RGB images with shape (224,224), while target is a 4-dim vector with one-hot encoding for the classes targets.

So, each call of **getitem** is returning, for example:

```
>> processed_images.shape
(5, 224, 224, 3)
>> target
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

In the training script, I'm extracting batch using:

```
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        drop_last=False,
        persistent_workers=False,
        timeout=0,
    )

for epoch in range(number_of_epochs):
    for batch_ind, batch_data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        datas, targets = batch_data
```

The problem is datas has the correct shape, i.e. a stack of 22 sequences of images:

```
datas.shape
torch.Size([22, 5, 224, 224, 3])
```

However, targets are stacked in a weird way:

```
len(targets) = 4
len(targets[0]) = 22
```

while I would expect the opposite (a list of 22 elements, each of len=4).
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the shape of the target that you return from __getitem__? It looks like the mistake is hapenning there.

Comment: Target as returned from __getitem__ is a list of 4 elements (for example, 
target=[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])

Comment: I would suggest you try making it a tensor. Having it as a list is probably messing the batching.

Comment: Where does ```weights``` come from? Shouldn't you your get_item method only return images and targets?

Comment: The weights was a typo, sorry!

Comment: SenseiH, I solved as you suggested, by converting target to Tensor before returning it from __getitem__, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated a minimum functioning code snippet from your description below (with a batch size 6 for a clearer output).

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "test"

    def __len__(self):
        return 100

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
         label = [0, 1.0, 0, 0]
         image = torch.randn((5, 3, 224, 224), dtype=torch.float32)
         return image, label

train_dataset = CustomImageDataset()
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=6,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=False,
    persistent_workers=False,
    timeout=0,
 )

for idx, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    datas = data[0]
    labels = data[1]
    print("Datas shape:", datas.shape)
    print("Labels:", labels)
    ("Labels shape:", len(labels))
    print("Labels[0] shape:", len(labels[0]))
    break
```

This code yields the following output:

```
Datas shape: torch.Size([6, 5, 3, 224, 224])
Labels: [tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
Labels shape: 4
Labels[0] shape: 6
```

As you can clearly see when inspecting `labels` your list gets appended elementwise to a tensor. I.e. all 0th elements of you one-hot-encoded lists are put in the same tensor. Namely the the 0th tensor of your `labels` list.

As this is not the outcome you expect (you want a list of 22 entries with one list for each one-hot-encoding) the easiest way is to directly define your label as a `torch.tensor([0, 1.0, 0, 0])` as suggested in the comment by SenseiH.

The adapted snipped would look like this:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "test"

    def __len__(self):
        return 100

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
         label = torch.tensor([0, 1.0, 0, 0])
         image = torch.randn((5, 3, 224, 224), dtype=torch.float32)
         return image, label

train_dataset = CustomImageDataset()
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=6,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=False,
    persistent_workers=False,
    timeout=0,
 )

for idx, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    datas = data[0]
    labels = data[1]
    print("Datas shape:", datas.shape)
    print("Labels:", labels)
    ("Labels shape:", len(labels))
    print("Labels[0] shape:", len(labels[0]))
    break
```

and the output is what you would expect:

```
Datas shape: torch.Size([6, 5, 3, 224, 224])
Labels: tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
Labels shape: torch.Size([6, 4])
```